# Cannot setup Drupal anymore

Tags: installation, 7

Ever since I switched to a brand new retina MacBook Pro, I'm not able to setup a new Drupal installation anymore...

I use MAMP and I configure my `vhosts.conf` so I can work on virtual hosts (like `dev.newproject.com`). But whenever I try to install a new Drupal installation, it looks like the setup is confused...

Normally, you have

```
 1. Choose profile
 2. Choose language
 3. Verify requirements
 4. Set up database
 5. Install profile
 6. Configure site
 7. Finished
```

But for some reason, after step 5, het installation goes back to step 1 or 3 or whatever step... When I look in my database, it looks like Drupal has been installed and also a `settings.php` file was created, but I'm in an infinite set-up loop...

Has anyone ever experienced such weird behaviour? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you disable JavaScript in your browser?
Perhaps you could try to clear all your browser's cache and cookies for this domain.
Does it happen on another browser?

Comment: It happens in all browsers with empty caches. And JavaScript is enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears more people suffer from this issue. It has nothing to do with the brand new retina structure.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527956/cant-install-drupal-7-24-using-mamp-on-osx-mavericks) on SE describes the same issue. Solution is waiting a few seconds WITOUT filling in the database credentials again and refresh the page. You'll see, the installation profile completes.

Answer (score 1):

It could be write permissions of the files - try `chmod -R a+rw .` command in Terminal in the root of your drupal folder. It could be a time out meaning that the database is not been written correctly (don't have a remedy for that, except for not using a native setup, but rather a Virtual Machine, VM-based setup...)

You might want to consider a VM-based setup (which would more closely resemble your production environment), see a guide I wrote to using Vagrant to automate generation of a setup here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15067918/227926

Comment: The Terminal command didn't work out... Could you summarise in 1 sentence the advantage of using Vagrant over MAMP? :)

Comment: OK here goes - my own words, in one sentence as requested "Vagrant provides a consistent, automated setup and that isolates the Drupal site from your machine's environment, allowing you to share your setup with others than can help/work with you."

Comment: P.S. Don't get put off by the length of instructions in the links I sent you. A particular Vagrant-based setup that works well for me is: http://github.com/mikebell/drupaldev-apache    Like you, I used to use MAMP but found myself starting to do quite a bit of manual setup and hacking for some things, stuff that wasn't easily containable and repeatable.

Comment: A further benefit of a Vagrant-based setup is that it is fairly isolated from any OS upgrade that might alter environmental settings on your machine. Vagrant is also multi platform, in that you can run your site stack on Linux or Windows machines too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MAMP error logs. It is very probably, than in a default MAMP installation (with no modifications), either your MySQL or PHP ran out of memory while in the midst of installing the default profile.

Also, did you take a look [at this answer?](https://drupal.org/node/158043) It has some excellent links.

Comment: I assigned 1024MB memory to PHP and MySQL, which met the criteria for years... So I doubt that's the issue. I only have 1 error in my logs and it has something to do with the `.DS_Store` file. Any change it has something to do with my issue?

Comment: Did you look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89651/horrific-errors-and-wsod/89660#89660 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/mysql-server-gone-away-while-loading-drupal-site-in-the-shared-environment/27127#27127? Memory is not the only thing that can give issues. Updated answer.

Comment: Non of the suggestions there are helpful I'm afraid... My `max allowed packet` is set to 1024M (more then enough I might think) and I'm not suffering any WSOD's.